Empty dateRangeInput() is giving an error
My previous question 1 was about managing empty dateRangeInput(). My previous question 2 was about error-handling when an initial date is posterior to an end date.
I have integrated the solutions to both questions into one code and it is running well. But when a daterange input is fully erased by hand (i.e. when any of the date boxes is made empty) it is giving an Error in if: missing value, TRUE/FALSE is required.
Can someone show me what is wrong or missing in the code below?
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rhandsontable)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(shinyalert)



DF1 <- data.table(
  "date" = as.character(NA),
  "docname" = as.character(NA),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

DF2 <- data.table(
  "date" = as.character(NA),
  "docname" = as.character(NA),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


ui <- fluidPage(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Tab1", tabName = "table1")
      )
    ),
    
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName = "table1",
                fluidRow(
                  column(
                    width = 8,
                    label=NULL,
                    rHandsontableOutput("table1Item1")
                  ),
                  column(
                    width = 6,
                    label=NULL,
                    selectInput("choices", label=NULL,
                                choices = c("choice 1", "choice 2")),
                    uiOutput("nested_ui1")
                  ),
                  column(
                    width = 8,
                    label=NULL,
                    rHandsontableOutput("table1Item2")
                  )
                )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  r <- reactiveValues(
    start = ymd(Sys.Date()),
    end = ymd(Sys.Date())
  )
  
  data <- reactiveValues()
  
  observe({
    data$df1 <- as.data.table(DF1)
    data$df2 <- as.data.table(DF2)
  })
  
  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$table1Item1)) {
      data$df1 <- hot_to_r(input$table1Item1)
    }
  })
  
  
  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$table1Item2)) {
      data$df2<- hot_to_r(input$table1Item2)
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$dates, {
    start <- ymd(input$dates[[1]])
    end <- ymd(input$dates[[2]])
    
    if (start > end) {
      shinyalert("Error: end date > initial date", type = "error")
      updateDateRangeInput(
        session, 
        "dates", 
        start = r$start,
        end = r$end
      )
    } else {
      r$start <- input$dates[[1]]
      r$end <- input$dates[[2]]
    }
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
  
  observe({ if (!is.null(input$table1Item1)) {
    data$df1 <- hot_to_r(input$table1Item1) 
    
    if (!any(is.na(input$dates)) && input$choices == "choice 1") {
      from=as.Date(input$dates[1L])
      to=as.Date(input$dates[2L])
      if (from>to) to = from
      selectdates1_1 <- seq.Date(from=from, to=to, by = "day")
      data$df2 <- data$df1[as.Date(data$df1$date) %in% selectdates1_1, ]
    } else if (!is.null(input$text) && input$choices == "choice 2") {
      data$df2 <- data$df1[data$df1$docname == input$text, ]
    } else {
      selectdates1_2 <- unique(data$df1$date)
      data$df2 <- data$df1[data$df1$date %in% selectdates1_2, ]
    }
  }
  })  
  
  output$table1Item1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(data$df1, stretchH = "all", height = 100,) |>
      hot_col(1, dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD", type = "date")
  })
  
  output$nested_ui1 <- renderUI({
    fluidRow(
      if (input$choices == "choice 1") {
        dateRangeInput("dates", "Choose date:", format="yyyy-mm-dd",
                       start = Sys.Date(), end = Sys.Date(), separator = "-")
      } else if (input$choices == "choice 2") {
        textInput("text", "Choose docname:")
      })
  })
  
  output$table1Item2 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(data$df2, stretchH = "all") |>
      hot_col(1, dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD", type = "date")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


The issue is that in your observeEvent(input$dates, ... you have the if condition if (start > end) and this can't handle things if start or end is NA (what is the case if the user clears the DateRangeInput).
You could circumvent this by using a tryCatch which in case of an error resets the DateRangeInput to Sys.Date() and throws a shinyalert that the DateRangeInput can't be empty and therefore was resetted, see the code below.

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rhandsontable)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(shinyalert)



DF1 <- data.table(
  "date" = as.character(NA),
  "docname" = as.character(NA),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

DF2 <- data.table(
  "date" = as.character(NA),
  "docname" = as.character(NA),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


ui <- fluidPage(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Tab1", tabName = "table1")
      )
    ),
    
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName = "table1",
                fluidRow(
                  column(
                    width = 8,
                    label=NULL,
                    rHandsontableOutput("table1Item1")
                  ),
                  column(
                    width = 6,
                    label=NULL,
                    selectInput("choices", label=NULL,
                                choices = c("choice 1", "choice 2")),
                    uiOutput("nested_ui1")
                  ),
                  column(
                    width = 8,
                    label=NULL,
                    rHandsontableOutput("table1Item2")
                  )
                )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  r <- reactiveValues(
    start = ymd(Sys.Date()),
    end = ymd(Sys.Date())
  )
  
  data <- reactiveValues()
  
  observe({
    data$df1 <- as.data.table(DF1)
    data$df2 <- as.data.table(DF2)
  })
  
  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$table1Item1)) {
      data$df1 <- hot_to_r(input$table1Item1)
    }
  })
  
  
  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$table1Item2)) {
      data$df2<- hot_to_r(input$table1Item2)
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$dates, {
    start <- ymd(input$dates[[1]])
    end <- ymd(input$dates[[2]])
    
    tryCatch({
      if (start > end) {
        shinyalert("Error: end date > initial date", type = "error")
        updateDateRangeInput(session,
                             "dates",
                             start = r$start,
                             end = r$end)
      } else {
        r$start <- input$dates[[1]]
        r$end <- input$dates[[2]]
      }
    }, error = function(e) {
      updateDateRangeInput(session,
                           "dates",
                           start = ymd(Sys.Date()),
                           end = ymd(Sys.Date()))
      shinyalert("DateRangeInput can't be empty! Resetting to Sys.Date().",
                 type = "error")
    })
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
  
  observe({ if (!is.null(input$table1Item1)) {
    data$df1 <- hot_to_r(input$table1Item1) 
    
    if (!any(is.na(input$dates)) && input$choices == "choice 1") {
      from=as.Date(input$dates[1L])
      to=as.Date(input$dates[2L])
      if (from>to) to = from
      selectdates1_1 <- seq.Date(from=from, to=to, by = "day")
      data$df2 <- data$df1[as.Date(data$df1$date) %in% selectdates1_1, ]
    } else if (!is.null(input$text) && input$choices == "choice 2") {
      data$df2 <- data$df1[data$df1$docname == input$text, ]
    } else {
      selectdates1_2 <- unique(data$df1$date)
      data$df2 <- data$df1[data$df1$date %in% selectdates1_2, ]
    }
  }
  })  
  
  output$table1Item1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(data$df1, stretchH = "all", height = 100,) |>
      hot_col(1, dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD", type = "date")
  })
  
  output$nested_ui1 <- renderUI({
    fluidRow(
      if (input$choices == "choice 1") {
        dateRangeInput("dates", "Choose date:", format="yyyy-mm-dd",
                       start = Sys.Date(), end = Sys.Date(), separator = "-")
      } else if (input$choices == "choice 2") {
        textInput("text", "Choose docname:")
      })
  })
  
  output$table1Item2 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(data$df2, stretchH = "all") |>
      hot_col(1, dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD", type = "date")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


dear Jan, your approach is something of an advanced level of coding. Thanks a lot for your time and effort!
